# How to use iframes in github

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

I ran into some problems with my iframes in github. I am making an incremental game which uses iframes to display different pages for each section of a bannner I have on top of the page. It works with textastic currently but not pages. The repository is here: https://github.com/VSquidDevV/IdleMiner

GitHub Page: 
http://vsquiddevv.github.io/IdleMiner/

Comment: Change line 21 of `index.html` to `<iframe src="pages/mainGame.html" frameborder="0" id="mainPageBody" width="1080px" height="1080px"></iframe>`

Comment: +1 for @hopkins-matt. You also have issues with url to `Pages` that will not work because of case sensitiveness `pages` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.. you reference the iframe outside of the repo, so it goes to
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/…/pages/mainGame.html`
instead of to a relative path `pages/mainGame.html`.

Change it in `index.html` in your github repo as was said by @hopkins-matt.

Answer (score 0):

Using `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/` doesn't work because of the X-Frame-Options problem, just use relative path is ok.